# Handling scrolling nested UIScrollViews scrolling in the same direction

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, uiscrollview

I am trying to implement something similar to Twitter iOS App (profile page)

This is view hierarchy:

- UIScrollView

  - Custom View
  - UITableView

  During scroll, once UIScrollView reaches certain y offset, (when UITableView gets to the top of the screen), then UITableView should start scroll. This needs to work in one continuous motion.

By default, this is not in continuous motion.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use one UITableView instead, with 2 sections, that's:

- UITableView:

  - Section 1:

    - Your 'Custom view' mentioned above
  - Section 2:

    - Your 'UITableView' mentioned above